# Reading multiple lines at a time in text file - C

Tags: c, file-io

I have an input file basically like this:

Group 1

Gabe Theodore Simon

Score 10

Group 2

Josh James Matthew

Score 9

I usually use fscanf in reading files but I do not know how to use it in reading three lines at a time. I am still new to c so can someone please help me?

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to say that the group members isn't always 3. It can even be hundreds

Comment: Why do you consider "reading three lines at a time" significantly different from "reading one line three times"?

Comment: You can use `fgets`?

Comment: Rad I don't get it can you please explain further? :)

Comment: RoadRunner, yeah maybe I'll try

Answer (score 2):

You can read line by line from the file using [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).

Something like this will get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 100

int
main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAXSIZE];

    fp = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading from file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAXSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
char group[32], name[128], score[32];
FILE *fp = fopen("score.txt", "r");
while(3 == fscanf(fp, "%31[^\n]%*c%127[^\n]%*c%31[^\n]%*c", group, name, score)){
    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", group, name, score);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: An elaboration on the fscanf's parameter in this example would be great. Is that a regex?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I refactored everything I had previously thought about. I am providing a fresh solution to get lines in a text file using C tools. I was able to achieved such by combining different programming techniques such as the following:

- [Regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)
- C provided functions:

  [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)   : collects the string
     [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) : checks for the end of the file

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define MAXSIZE 500

  int
  main(void) {
      char line[MAXSIZE];
      while (scanf("%499[^\n]", line)== 1 && getchar() != EOF) {
      printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    return 0;
  }
  ```

Steps to run this C code from terminal:

1. Create a text file
2. Compile the C code
3. Run it by [redirecting text file](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php): ./(executable_goes_here) < (text_file_created_goes_here)

Comment: He will be reading from a file, not `stdin`. No point showing `scanf`.

Comment: Hey @RoadRunner you can actually use scanf() to read from file as well.  If you like I can provide an elaborated example.

Comment: Yeah you can if you use input redirection I guess. Not sure OP wants to do that though.

Comment: `Group 1` has space. `%s` can't have space. (So `"%s %s %s"` can't _use it in reading three lines at a time_.)

Comment: I was able to run an example just like that and it worked out perfect @BLUEPIXY I am working in a full example for you guys as we speak.

Comment: Not all people have middle names, so I think that your suggested example will not work properly.

Comment: I have not provided the example just yet...  I am aware that we will encounter different input size.  I will make sure it works on all cases.

Comment: There are groups with hundreds of members I dont think it would be good to put hundreds of %s

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have provided a solution using scanf() and an additional function provided by C

Comment: `"%500[^\n]"` --> `"%499[^\n]"`

Comment: Thanks for the observation, @blu

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you think of that solution ?